# Can I extract and send information about watching videos on web browsers

Tags: youtube

What I want to do is to provide users with a booklet (such as Instapaper's), which will send information (e.g., clicked time) about streaming video the users are watching when they click on it

For example, if I click on the point on 1m45s of a certain YouTube video, it sends the time to a server.

I don't know much about YouTube and its API, but my guess is it would be difficult to do from watching a standard youtube player (at youtube.com for example), but might be possible on a customized youtube player using youtube player api?

I apologize that I jumped to asking before putting much effort into the APIs, but as I'm just evaluating possibilities rather than planning implementations, please regard this as more like a can-I question rather than a detailed how-to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. You will need to use the flash player and the Javascript API. The latter provides a means to get the current time of the video being played. You can also of course get listen for play event and then retrieve the current time and use an XHR request to send it to your server.
The best overview of all this is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link was very helpful. Does it mean a javascript bookmarklet can call a YouTube API function such as getCurrentTime() for a video being played from arbitrary servers? Maybe with some restrictions? Or can getCurrentTime() be called only be the same HTML source that embeds the YouTube video?

Comment: I accepted your answer for giving me a guide but please teach me about the question I left in the comment when you have a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sort of. Remember that JS bookmarklets need to be clicked on in order to run. It is not like you have some background process running that can sniff what the user is doing. Also, you will run into the JS security model of dis-allowing cross-site scripting calls, so no AJAX is allowed in the bookmarklet only a direct call to your backend, which will of course cause the browser to change the current page. So if your idea was to make a generic video-bookmark scriptlet you are screwed. However, for your own site there is no reason you couldn't track or log this kind of stuff.

Comment: Perfect. That's all I wanted to know. Thanks you so much!